# Returning function values as float Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, function, math, hypotenuse

I get the following error and can't seem to figure out how to fix. Following the logic, i'm calling 3 functions and all 3 return values as float and then I'm performing some math operation on the stored returned values and print it as float. So where did it go wrong? I enter 4 for side A and 5 for side B.

The error message:

Enter the length of side A:  4.0
Enter the length of side B:  5.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 26, in <module>
  File "python", line 9, in main
  File "python", line 24, in calculateHypotenuse
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'
```

---

```
import math

def main():
  #Call get length functions to get lengths.
  lengthAce = getLengthA()
  lengthBee = getLengthB()

  #Calculate the length of the hypotenuse
  lengthHypotenuse = calculateHypotenuse(float(lengthAce),float(lengthBee))

  #Display length of C (hypotenuse)
  print()
  print("The length of side C 'the hypotenuse' is {}".format(lengthHypotenuse))

#The getLengthA function prompts for and returns length of side A  
def getLengthA():
  return float(input("Enter the length of side A: "))

#The getLengthA function prompts for and returns length of side B
def getLengthB():
  return float(input("Enter the length of side B: "))

def calculateHypotenuse(a,b):
  return math.sqrt(a^2 + b^2)

main()

print()
print('End of program!')
```

Comment: If you're trying to use the power operator, you need to use `**` instead. `^` has a completely different meaning in Python. It's the bitwise XOR operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` in Python is the [*bitwise XOR operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-xor_expr), not the power operator:

> The ^ operator yields the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) of its arguments, which must be intege

You need to use `**` instead, which *is* the power operator:

```
def calculateHypotenuse(a,b):
  return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

Comment: Glad to help @Cornel!